# Simulate the audio amplifier using the circuit shown

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, simulation, homework, multisim

Okay so I've done the exact same thing in Multisim but I don't know how to find the voltage again. I tried to place the multimeter in the audio (where I have placed the multimeter) but the values vary and when I put it in AC, there's no values at all

[image: required]

[image: the one i did]

Answer (score 0):

Multimeter tool isn’t best to find voltage gain. Better approach is to attach an oscilloscope. Connect input of amplifier to channel 1 of oscilloscope  and output of amplifier to channel 2 of oscilloscope. Then take peak values of each waveform to determine gain.

Second option is to do a transient simulation. First right click on input node, and label it Vin. Similarly, right click output and label it Vout. Then you’d have to go to simulate, pick transient, choose a stop time that is 5 to 10 times the period of input. Also choose Vin and Vout as output variables, then click run.

As an alternative, you can also simulate an AC sweep. First right click on input node, and label it Vin. Similarly, right click output and label it about. Then you’d have to go to simulate, pick ac sweep, make the expression Vout/Vin, and plot. Then you I can determine gain over wide range of frequency.

NOTE: You need to add a load resistor to output, try 100kohm.